# Insert Image into a pdf at a specified location

Tags: python, image-processing, pypdf

I'm relatively new to python, and I'm trying to replace an image at a given location.
The idea is to check if the extracted image in the PDF matches the image I want to replace. If it does, I extract the location and put the new image in its place. I'm done with the extracting and checking part. Could someone please help me with the later part?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: convert mypdf.pdf to full_page_image.jpg

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('mypdf.pdf', 500)
pages[x].save('full_page_image.jpg', 'JPEG') #where x is your page number minus one
```

Step 2: overlay image_to_be_added onto full_page_image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
full_page_image = cv2.imread('full_page_image.jpg')
image_to_be_added = cv2.imread('image_to_be_added.jpg')
final_image = full_page_image.copy()
final_image[100:400,100:400,:] = image_to_be_added[100:400,100:400,:] #adjust the numbers according to the dimensions of the image_to_be_added
cv2.imwrite(final_image.jpg, final_image)
```

Step3: convert final_image.jpg to final_pdf.pdf

```
from PIL import Image
final_image2 = Image.open(r'final_image.jpg')
final_image3 = final_image2.convert('RGB')
final_image3.save(r'final_pdf.pdf')
```

Comment: Hey,
I'm getting an error in step 3.  ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (133,300,3) into shape (300,300,3)

Comment: The dimensions should be the same, I believe. Your dimensions are different. Resize it to make it same before you insert.